# How does a modern compiler go about optimizing this code

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

How would a modern compiler optimize this code:

```
int fn (int a, int b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=4*a; i>0; i--)
    {
        sum += b*i*i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Compile and look!

Comment: @churill the `&gt;` is the html-sanitized replacement for `>`. So he is just looping from 4 times `a` to 1.

Comment: If you wanted to optimize it by hand, this is b * (sum of n^2 for n=1..4a), and there's a formula for the sum of squares: (2n^3 + 3n^2 + n) / 6 for 1..n. So substituting, the result is 4b(32a^3 + 16a^2 + a)/6 for positive a. No idea if a compiler would generate that for your or not though.

Comment: check the assembly code generated from your code with different flags in https://godbolt.org/

Comment: All compilers will provide you options that allow you to dump the assembly generated by the compiler to a file. You can simply save the code above and then compile with the varying different levels of optimization outputting the assembly in different files to compare. How the compiler optimizes will be compiler and hardware specific. ARM optimizations will differ from x86 will differ from x86_64, etc.. @nayab has the right idea -- and you can let godbolt do it for you...

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer to this question, as there are many compilers, and many flags that can modify the compilation and optimizations used, and different optimizations may be used depending on the target architecture.

Your best try is going to [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/13a1qW) and checking the assembly generated by different compilers with different flags. You need to understand assembly if you want to compare the outputs. As you can see, latest versions of gcc and clang produced very different versions for the same code, and same optimization level.